# How do I cancel Asp.net wizard FinishButtonClick event?

Tags: asp.net, wizard

When the Finish button is clicked, I'd like to stay on the final step in case of validation failure. How do I achieve this?

```
if(!valid) e.Cancel = true;
```

works for `NextButtonClick` event for intermediate steps but not for `FinishButtonClick` event. What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is annoying that the cancel doesn't do what you would expect!
You can stop the Wizard "finishing" by setting:

```
Wizard1.FinishDestinationPageUrl = String.Empty;
```

if validation fails and setting it to the page you want to go to if all is ok.